# Is value inside Static Variable would dissapear if the device restarted?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to build apps that runs alarm every day. But the alarm will start based on data from webserver.

This is the activity flow :

1. First installation i have to input id into textbox and submit the button in activity A. The submit button function is to retrieve some value from webserver in json form.
2. After get the result, the value will be passed into Activity B (Broadcastreceiver).

The question is the value that has been passed into BroadCastReceiver will be gone after reboot or not ?

Comment: You will need to have a bootreceiver and re set your alarm. Check the  link for **Start an Alarm When the Device Boots**. And you will need to store those values some where in shared preferences or sqlite database

Comment: There is no link in your comment

Comment: Sorry here's the link to the documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot

Comment: Thx for your reply. What shared preferences do you mean ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, static variables have scope of class only. Its value will go after reboot.

Save required value in `Preference` if you want it to preserve after reboot.

Comment: what Preference do you mean ?

Comment: [Preference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) Read this its easy

Comment: Preference is a way to store your data in key-value sets in a file so that it can be read anywhere from your application. Also it remains in file and not deleted even if user close the application.

Comment: @AzimAnsari preferences will not help actually setting the alarm again after reboot cause the alarm is washed away after reboot

Comment: But after reboot. It will be required to restore that value. Which can be done using Preference.

Comment: Which one is if i have a value in activity A but i want to open that value from activity B ?